# Entropy change in particle electric dipole alignment

Tags: electrical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics

Suppose a bunch of micron sized particles are charged positively on one half of their surface, and negative on the other. If they are arranged randomly, I understand they will have high entropy, as the system is in disorder.

If under the influence of an electric field, we shake these particles such that they align themselves (they will, right?), the dipoles are now in the state of least energy and the system is more ordered, so I understand the entropy must have decreased? Yes, not the total entropy, just the particles themselves.

Is my understanding correct, and if yes, will this bring a decrease in temperature of the particles?

Before:
[image]

After applying electric field and shaking:
[image]

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/167989/does-a-magnetic-field-decrease-or-increase-entropy

Comment: @TigerGuy I am talking about large particles. This seems to be about molecules. Also, the magnetocaloric effect is different than electrocaloric. Please guide me you legend : )